# Azure Media Services AAD Token C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-media-services

Currently I'm having a very hard time trying to integrate AAD with Azure Media Services.
I have to get a bearer token from AAD and then pass that token to Azure Media Player to play an encrypted video, but I always get the following error: Unable to decrypt the encrypted video source. (0x20500004).

Here goes two snippets of the code that I'm using.
C# Code:

```
string tenant = "xxxxxxxxxcom.onmicrosoft.com";
string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx";
string clientSecret = "xxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxx=";
var tokenCredentials = new AzureAdTokenCredentials(tenant, new AzureAdClientSymmetricKey(clientId, clientSecret), AzureEnvironments.AzureCloudEnvironment);
var tokenProvider = new AzureAdTokenProvider(tokenCredentials);
var token = tokenProvider.GetAccessToken();
```

[C# Code Integration With Azure AAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KnkY.png)

The "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client" version is 4.1

Asp.net/JavaScript Code:

```
<script>
    var playerOptions = {
        "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
        controls: true,
        autoplay: true,
        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",
        techOrder: ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "html5FairPlayHLS", "silverlightSS", "html5"],
        logo: {
            enabled: true
        },
        poster: "https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/assetxxxxxxxx-xxxx-410d-xxxx-7xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx11563.jpg?sv=2015-07-08&sr=c&si=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxb%2F%2FTlyHLU6DTcf%2FdfWMaMSqw%3D&se=2078-06-12T16%3A08%3A03Z",
        plugins: {
            ga: {
                'eventsToTrack': ['playerConfig', 'loaded', 'playTime', 'percentsPlayed', 'start', 'end', 'play', 'pause', 'error', 'buffering', 'fullscreen',     'seek', 'bitrate'],
                'debug': false
            }
        }
    };    
    var playerSrc = [{
        src: "http://xxxxxxxxx.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx/xxxxxx.ism/manifest" + "(format=m3u8-aapl)",
        "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml",
        "protectionInfo": [{
            "type": "AES",
            "authenticationToken": "Bearer @ViewBag.Token"
        }],
        "streamingFormats":["SMOOTH","DASH"]
    }];
</script>
```

[Asp.net/JavaScript Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOgeo.png)

The link for Azure Player is: https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html

Comment: Please, put your code inside your question, not as a link.

Comment: @JeroenHeier, done!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figure out how to solve this problem. Follow the steps that I did:

1. If you don’t use azure media services explorer, grab it here: github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer. This will make your life easier managing the videos.
2. Choose your video source and click with the right button on it. Select “Encode  Encode asset(s) with Media Encoder Standard (MES)”.
3. Choose “Content Adaptive Multiple Bitrate MP4” and click “Launch encoding”.
   [Img for step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwc5K.png)
4. After the job is done. Right click in generated file and them “Security  Add dynamic encryption and key delivery policies for the asset(s)”.
   [Img for step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL6ga.png)
5. Choose the protection “Envelope clear key”
   [Img for step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO7vT.png)
6. Next steps, use default: Step 2 – Automatic Generation, Step 3 - Yes, define an authorization policy for the content key with 1 option(s).
7. Step 3, Content key’s authorization policy option: Token. Token Type: SWT – Simple Web Token. Token Properties: Fill both issuer and Audience. After that click “Ok”
   [Img for step 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rse5c.png)
8. On the video that you just encrypted, right click and select “Publish  Create a locator”. Leave the options as it is and click on create button.
   [Img for step 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4jLF.png)
9. Right click on the video and click “Display Information” or press F4.
10. Select the “Content keys” tab, then select “Content Envelope” and keep the “ID” and “restriction requirements” (TokenRestrictionTemplate XML).
    [Img for step 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5CCk.png)
11. Play the media. Right click on the video and click “Playback  with azure media player”. Click on the button “Create test token” when you asked for.
    [Img for step 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arazH.png)
12. When the browser open, take a look at “Protection Bearer”. This field is where you will update the token.
    [Img for step 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmcoz.png)
13. Now the C# code (sorry, I don't know why the code format don't was applied):

    string tokenTemplateString = "{{Paste here the XML that you got at step 10 (Restriction Requirements)}}";
    TokenRestrictionTemplate tokenTemplate =
                TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.Deserialize(tokenTemplateString);
    string testToken = TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.GenerateTestToken(tokenTemplate, tokenTemplate.PrimaryVerificationKey, new Guid("Paste here the ID that you got at step 10. Remove the "nb:kid:UUID:" part!"), DateTime.Now.AddHours(10));
    Console.WriteLine("The authorization token is:\nBearer {0}", testToken);
14. Use the generated token in the field marked at step 12. Don't forgot to use the word "Bearer "

Comment: These steps have changed somewhat for AMS Explorer v3 but for the functionality remains. there is now "Security" option however Right Click->Publish->Clear key Streaming->Create Locator effectively replaces steps 4 and 5.